# How to return the Index when slicing Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, slice

```
 df2=   pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[:, [n for n in random.sample(range(1, 7), 3)]])
```

> returns df1 rows and selected columns but it returns a generic index 0,1,2,3..etc instead
>   of   returning       the Datetime index of df1 which is what I want to keep. I tried:

```
df2=df1.copy(deep=True)

df2= pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)
df2= df1.iloc[:, [n for n in random.sample(range(1, 7), 3)]]
```

but it does not work...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.ix[:,random.sample(range(1,7),3)])
```

This will give the result you wanted.

```
df1
Out[130]: 
   one  two
d  NaN  4.0
b  2.0  2.0
c  3.0  3.0
a  1.0  1.0

df1.ix[:,random.sample(range(0,2),2)]
Out[131]: 
   two  one
d  4.0  NaN
b  2.0  2.0
c  3.0  3.0
a  1.0  1.0
```

This will randomly sample your columns and returns them in df2. This will return all the rows of the randomly sampled columns with index as was in df1.

Edit-
As MaxU has suggested, you can simply use:

```
df2 = df1.ix[:, random.sample(df.columns.tolist(), 3)].copy()
```

instead of calling the pd.DataFrame() constructor.

Comment: hi @Harshavardhan Ramanna thanks! But I am not sampling on the rows i am sampling on the columns ; i only select a random subset of columns, not necessarily adjacent ones, and I dlike to return that subset of columns, its rows, and the original index which is in Datetime Format. However, so far i return a generic integer index.. thanks..

Comment: Check out the edited answer. I think this should work.

Comment: you don't need to call `pd.DataFrame()` constructor, you can simply do this: `df2 = df1.ix[:, random.sample(df.columns.tolist(), 3)].copy()`

Answer (score 0):

what about slightly different approach?

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]:
            c1  c2  c3
2016-01-01   4   0   3
2016-01-02   2   3   2
2016-01-03   1   2   3
2016-01-04   3   3   0
2016-01-05   1   0   4
2016-01-06   1   1   1
2016-01-07   2   3   3
2016-01-08   2   2   2
2016-01-09   4   0   0
2016-01-10   1   1   0
2016-01-11   1   3   0
2016-01-12   4   3   1
2016-01-13   0   0   3
2016-01-14   3   1   0
2016-01-15   4   3   1

In [67]: rnd = df.sample(n=6)

In [68]: rnd.index
Out[68]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-04', '2016-01-03', '2016-01-12', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-13'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [69]: rnd
Out[69]:
            c1  c2  c3
2016-01-04   3   3   0
2016-01-03   1   2   3
2016-01-12   4   3   1
2016-01-02   2   3   2
2016-01-01   4   0   3
2016-01-13   0   0   3
```

Comment: hi thanks for the fast answer! however this returns the locus of the index but doesnt not return the actual Datetime string i.e: "2016-08-11" of the indices. This is the return i got:                                                    RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1305, step=1)

Comment: thnks! but.. I get this                                                                TypeError: cannot convert Int64Index->DatetimeIndex

Comment: I can't reproduce this error - what step/command produces this exception? Actually something like `df.iloc[[5,0,4,3]].index` returns `DatetimeIndex` as well...

Comment: i did this: df2 =   (df1.iloc[:, [n for n in random.sample(range(1, 7), 4)]])
    sample1=pd.DatetimeIndex(df2.index)
    print(sample1)

Comment: @Pythus, can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: basically iam sample the original Dataframe df1for random columns, not necessarily adjacent, and then I want to get a new Dataframe df2 with those columns and rows taken from df1, with and most important the original Datetime Index that was in df1. Then afterwards i apply a function on the entire df2..

Comment: this is what i get using your approach: Int64Index([775, 268, 507, 423, 552, 736, 233, 1119, 8], dtype='int64')

Comment: @MaxU He is trying to shuffle the columns in df1 and take a random subset of those columns.  He wants the index to be the same as that of df1, i.e, df2 is not shuffled or sampled row-wise